# What is difference between screen size and pixel size?

Tags: graphics, window, glfw, resolution, vulkan

I'm reading the [Vulkan documentation](https://docs.vulkan.org/tutorial/latest/03_Drawing_a_triangle/01_Presentation/01_Swap_chain.html#_swap_extent)  on how to set the swap chain size. And I don't understand what the difference is between screen sizes and pixel sizes. How does PPI affect the screen coordinates? For example, we have a 1920 x 1080 monitor with small PPI. If I create a 960 x 540 window, it will be half the size. If we have a 3840 x 2160 monitor and it has a much higher DPI, that window will be 4 times smaller. This is exactly what is logically expected. Maybe I'm wrong and this glfw window is scaled during creation and will also occupy half of second monitor, but I don't know how to check it. I have only one monitor and I have not found clear examples on the Internet. I mean window resolution is not relative, so why PPI influences on it? Help me please I am totally puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

The term *resolution* is a badly overloaded word.  I've always tried to avoid using it when describing frame buffer or monitor pixel dimensions.  And I don't complain when others use the term this way as it is common practice and is described really well here in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution).  The article even says that using it to describe pixel dimensions is a misnomer and that the proper usage is for pixel density (DPI).

That being said, the Vulkan API has you specifying windows in terms of *display resolution* (pixel dimensions) and the actual physical size of the window depends on the monitor's pixel density.  If you wanted to draw something that measures 1 inch on the monitor, you'd have to query the monitor's DPI and then figure out how many pixels to draw.

This sort of usage may not be common.  A more frequent issue is drawing text on high-DPI displays where you have to take some steps to draw the text with more pixels in order to be able to read it and/or retain the expected point size.